# Raise TemplateNotFound(template) jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am just providing a piece of code here. When i run the whole code its showing Index.html file is not found.

```
 app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.url_map.converters['everything'] = EverythingConverter

    def render(duplicates, current, total):
        env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('template'))
        template = env.get_template('index.html')
        return template.render(duplicates=duplicates,
                               current=current,
                               total=total)
```

the error is

```
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

My file path is

```
/My_project
   template
      /index.html
   my_project.py
```

I ran the program so many times but its writes the same error. Does anyone had some idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: I have been learning flask for like a month I have never come across something like this. Where did you learn this?

Comment: Hey its just a source code. you can find at [https://github.com/philipbl/duplicate-images]. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/layout/) your project layout should look something like this:

```
my_project/
│ 
├── templates/
│   └── base.html 
│   
├── static/
│   └── style.css
│ 
└── app.py
```

The directory in which you store your templates should be named:

> templates/

Instead of:

> template/

**Don't forget to change references to this directory as well.**

Comment: Hey Ninjajoshuadx, I changed the total folder structure as you said but the error remains the same. you can see the full code at [https://github.com/philipbl/duplicate-images]. thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Akasha Did you also change the the "template" in `env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('template'))` to "templates"?

Comment: Yeah i changed the template to templates. But the error remains same.

Comment: I have tested your script on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Raspbian (command-line). The following steps were taken:
(1) `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, (2) `pip3 install pymongo==3.4.0`, (3) `sudo apt -y install mongodb-server python3-pip`, (4) `sudo systemctl disable mongodb.service`, (5) `sudo service mongodb stop`, (6) `python3 duplicate_finder.py add tests/images/`, and (7) `python3 duplicate_finder.py find`.

The result (without any changes to the code after clone): https://imgur.com/a/cgqWUcf.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah that worked But there is some problem with my PC. I tried with another computer that's working.